# Mysql.data doesn't have SqlDataAdapter even with the latest dotnet core 2.0?

Tags: mysql, .net-core

dotnet core 2 has been released recently and I've now converting my projects...
and I found that mysql connectors for dotnet core are still not ready.
Or what am I missing here? I've tried both beta/pre versions on nuget, those are

8.0.8-dmr
and
6.10.3-rc

Both don't have DataAdapter.

I tried the official one, they do. System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter works fine. But of course that thing can only cope with mssqlserver so. here I'm asking. Does it?

And, btw, what's the difference of those 2? I couldn't find release note on nuget neither.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue :(

Comment: Alternatively, you can use Dapper.Net. That is what I am using.

Comment: i have used 8.0.8-dmr a LOT with a wrapper class. I am sure the nuget would directly work as well. What functionality exactly are you looking for DataAdapter for?